# Attempting to isolate all lines containing a specific word and edit one value

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to isolate all lines in the document (of which there are 300k+) that contain a specific word. The first task would be `index="151"`. Every line containing that string I need to change, and only change the `color` code.

As an example -

```
<item parent="9463" index="9476">
<block lx="2.34999752" ly="6.58951187" lz="16.3749924" ux="2.39999676" uy="6.63951397" uz="16.8749962" index="151" material="3" look="0" up="3" color="ffcd0000"/>
```

I need this to remain exactly the same, except for the `color` string, and I need this done for all items containing the index value 151. There are 4606 in the document, but I assume that is irrelevant.

Also, this is just one of dozens of index color changes I need to make. I have tried other methods, but they break the structure of the document and that corrupts it.

I suspect there is an simple solution, but nothing I've tried has worked. One more thing... you'll perhaps notice that the item contains two `index` values,  the first being 9476 and the second being 151. I would need to adjust the index value of 151 (or rather the color value of index 151, not the index value itself) and leave the first index value (9476) completely alone.

Thanks. - I am working with an XML file.

Desired result -

```
<item parent="9463" index="9476">
<block lx="2.34999752" ly="6.58951187" lz="16.3749924" ux="2.39999676" uy="6.63951397" uz="16.8749962" index="151" material="3" look="0" up="3" color="ffcd0001"/>
```

Not being wildly familiar with Notepad ++ the things I have tried revolved around bookmarks. Copying specific lines, pasting then in another project and editing them there, however I can't bring those changes back into my original project without changing the structure.

Comment: (1) Don’t post pictures of text. Post text as text. (2) Please don’t post examples of text that have lines longer than 80 characters or so unless you really need to. And you don’t need to here. (3) Are you talking about a text file that just happens to contain a lot of `<`, `>`, `=` and `"` characters, or are you talking about processing XML? If you’re talking about a text file, then the fact that you have ```index="9476"``` on one line and ```index="151"``` on another line is irrelevant. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … If you’re talking about finding an XML thing based on a value that appears on one line and then changing a value that appears on another line, that’s a different kettle of fish *and **you need to say that that’s what you’re talking about**.* (4) First you say you want to change the `color` value on the same line as the `index` value, and then you say that you want to change the `index` value itself. Which is it? Show an example of the desired output. (5) What have you tried? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Can I assume these changes satisfies your criteria?

Comment: Crossposted to [the Notepad++ Community Forum](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17171/attempting-to-isolate-all-lines-containing-a-specific-word-and-edit-one-value) and answered there.